# Only one JS script is executed on page load

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have the following html head which loads 3 JS files: search.js, create.js and maps.js:

```
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/maps.css" />
      <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<my-key>=initMap"
    async defer></script>
      <script src="/search.js"></script>
      <script src="/create.js"></script>
      <script src="/maps.js"></script>

  </head>
```

I also have the following server side code:

```
var express = 
require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('meetup listening on port 3000!')
})
```

when index.html loads, the client seems to only execute one JS script (tested by logging 'script x loaded' in each file). The executed script is always the last one loaded in the head. (i.e. if `<script src="/search.js"></script>` is last then console will only log 'script search.js loaded'). The executed script always works as expected. The other scripts are all loading in the js console, but they do not execute. Any thoughts on what's wrong here?

EDIT: all three scripts look something like

```
window.onload = (function(){
    console.log('search.js loaded');

/*
*event handling and DOM manipulation logic here
*/
});
```

FIXED:replaced `window.onload = (function(){...});` with   `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the contents of the scripts.

Comment: using the browser developer tools network tab, can you confirm the content of the scripts is correct

Comment: yea, it doesn't seem to be cacheing related. All scripts have expected content.

Comment: So I assume `search.js` , `create.js` & `map.js` are in your static folder.?

Comment: yea those are all in static

Comment: Please give us the content of the scripts.

Comment: read errors from console.

Comment: Do your scripts depend on the google maps api script? If they are trying to call methods defined in that script you will have problems because that script tag has both `async` and `defer` attributes so it could load after your other scripts. Try removing async and defer and see if there is a difference.

Comment: Remove the google maps one, see if they load. The "async and defer" seem to be the biggest hints.

If that does nothing, take everything out of the three JS files except 
console.log('name of the script');.

That'll see if it's the content that blocks it.

Comment: I tried both taking out the google maps one and taking out all the content from the scripts other than the console.log and the problem is still the same. There aren't any console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably related to how you have set your event handler in your scripts. You can only have one event handlder for 'window.onload" event, the way you have shown. Thus, all the other event handlers for the same event won't be called when scripts are loaded.
Try using something like:

```
window.addEventListener("onload", function(){
  console.log('I am loaded');
});
```

Using the above, you can have multiple event handlers listening for the same event, which in this case is the onload event.
I hope this helps.

Comment: dont you mean [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Comment: indeed, thanks for the correction. I must have been half asleep.